# What is the equivalent of Visual Studio Configuration Manager in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: build, visual-studio-code, compilation, vscode-tasks

I build an app using Visual Studio Code and get the error "Cognitive Services Speech SDK doesn't support 'Any CPU' as a platform". I try various things but cannot get it to compile.

I build the same app using Visual Studio 2017 and get the same error which I easily fix by changing the platform to from AnyCPU to x64 in the Configuration Manager.

So, what is the equivalent of Configuration Manager in Visual Studio Code so I can fix the problem there too?

I tried setting the target platform in the .csproj and in the build command in Visual Studio Code but still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `dotnet build` as your command to build a dotnet application you will need to specify some additional command line args when running the command. Visual Studio essentially does the same when calling the compiler, but adds a nice UI to manage it in.

`dotnet build --runtime win10-x64`

The above would build for a x86 Windows 10 machine, we tell the compiler to do this with the `--runtime` flag and pass in a RID `win10-x64`, each environment you're building for will have a different RID (an example linux RID for example would be `linux-x64`).

- You can read more about the dotnet compiler options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build)
- Get a list of the RIDs supported [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)

---

**Build Configurations**

You say you're running the build command, so I assume that you're typing these into the console. But VS Code does give some additional niceness to managing environments through the `tasks.json` file.

Here you can define a set of commands to run and save them as a configuration, then pick these through the UI. I won't go into too much detail as it's well documented, but here's a build config that would run the dotnet compiler with the x64 command!

[More info on VS Code Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "--runtime",
                "win10-x64"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> you will get a list of your configured build tasks!